# EF DB first generates errors when Add Code Generation Items

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to run the Code Generation for my edmx, however every time I do this, I'm being faced with lots of errors.

This is the Context.cs file is generated:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/ <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace project.DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class NebulabEntities : DbContext
    {
        public NebulabEntities()
            : base("name=NebulabEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CommoditiesPrice> CommoditiesPrices { get; set; }

     }
}
```

The Errors I'm getting:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0426  The type name 'Data' does not exist in the type 'System'    project.DAL C:\Test\project.DAL\RedSpiderDataModel.Context.cs   13
Error   CS0426  The type name 'Data' does not exist in the type 'System'    project.DAL C:\Test\project.DAL\RedSpiderDataModel.Context.cs   14
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) project.DAL C:\Test\project.DAL\RedSpiderDataModel.Context.cs   16
Error   CS0115  'NebulabEntities.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override project.DAL C:\Test\project.DAL\RedSpiderDataModel.Context.cs   23
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbModelBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    project.DAL C:\Test\project.DAL\RedSpiderDataModel.Context.cs   23
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbSet<Commodity>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  project.DAL C:\Test\project.DAL\RedSpiderDataModel.Context.cs   28
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbSet<CommoditiesPrice>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   project.DAL C:\Test\project.DAL\RedSpiderDataModel.Context.cs   29
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for this, and I've added EF to my class library project.

Does anyone know why it's generating code with errors?

Comment: have you got the solution i am facing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are referencing older entity framework dll in your project. The solution is - 
1. First remove the reference of older EF dll from Reference Manager. 
2. Then add the Newer EF dll by using the browser feature.

For EF 6.1.3 you will get the dll in the folder "EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45"

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go.  I thought I made sure I removed all the references of EF before, but I might have missed one reference.